# What is the cause of "TypeError: not all arguments covered during string formatting" when trying to import data into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to export CSV files into MySQL databases, but I can't seem to figure out the error with my code. I believe it should be working.

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mysql_conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='******', db='accounting')
mysql_cursor = mysql_conn.cursor()

f = open('C:/Users/Pops/Desktop/List of Payees.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    mysql_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO list_of_payees (list_of_payees) VALUES (%s)""", (row[0]))

mysql_conn.commit()
mysql_cursor.close()
```

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Programming\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 238, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pops/Desktop/Martin/Programming/Python/ExcelToMySQL.py", line 11, in <module>
    mysql_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO list_of_payees (list_of_payees) VALUES (%s)""", (row[0]))
  File "C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Programming\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 240, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m))
  File "C:\Users\Pops\Desktop\Martin\Programming\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 52, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass(errorvalue)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute's second parameter represents a list of the objects to be converted.

`mysql_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO list_of_payees (list_of_payees) VALUES (%s)""", (row[0]))`

This line is the problem, as `row[0]` is expected to be a list

You could try going with `mysql_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO list_of_payees (list_of_payees) VALUES '%s'", [row[0]])`

Also alternatively you can try adding a comma to the end of your row value `mysql_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO list_of_payees (list_of_payees) VALUES '%s'", (row[0],))`

Comment: Thank you the 2nd one works. Although I believe the `'%s'` should be `(%s)`

Answer (score 1):

[LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) is a faster and better approach to upload the csv files to MYSQL table, Reading CSV and Inserting into MYSQL table is a slow and time taking process. Use MYSQLdb to execute this command from python.

Sample Query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path_of_csv_file/sampledata.csv' 
INTO TABLE expenses  
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or \r\n
(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice